# How do I use the fingerprintjs2 library?

Tags: javascript, fingerprintjs2

I am trying to use fingerprintjs2 for the identification of devices. However, I am new to using Libraries and I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Fingerprint2 is not defined`.

Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2"></script>
<script>
    if (window.requestIdleCallback) {
        requestIdleCallback(function () {
            Fingerprint2.get(function (components) {
                console.log(components) // an array of components: {key: ..., value: ...}
            })
        })
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            Fingerprint2.get(function (components) {
                console.log(components) // an array of components: {key: ..., value: ...}
            })
        }, 500)
    }
</script>
```

Can someone tell me why this is not working? I have done the yarn install to this.

Is this not the correct way to use javascript libraries?

Also, please tell me if there are any alternatives to remembering devices, however, there seems to be none as far as I have done some research.

Edit:

I am now thinking that it might be about CORS since it gives the warning: `Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://cdnjs.com/libraries/fingerprintjs2 with MIME type text/html`

Comment: use `https://cdnjs.com/libraries/fingerprintjs2` instead of github url

Comment: It still gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by downloading the file locally and setting the source of the script to that `fingerprint2.js` file

Answer (score 0):

In my case, download all the github repository and install it locally in my plugins folder is working. After that, you can minify it again.